# How to return data to out of function in koa with mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, koa

i made code like this.

but I can't get data at out of functon, collections.findOne.

I wanna make that function return data took from database.

and finally, I wanna redirect 'http://localhost:5000/main'.

So I tried 'ctx.redirect="/main" ' in collections.findOne function.

But it was not working.

How can i solve these?

```
require('dotenv').config();
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';
const serve = require('koa-static');

const bodyparser = require('koa-body');

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const Router = require('koa-router');

const router = new Router();

app.use(bodyparser());
app.use(serve('../client/review-app/dist/review-app'));
app.use(router.routes());
MongoClient.connect(url, async (err, db) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  const dbo = db.db('review');

  // router.get('/', (ctx, next) => {});

  router.post('/loginAsk', (ctx, next) => {
    // ctx.redirect(`www.naver.com`);
    const { id } = ctx.request.body;
    const { pw } = ctx.request.body;

    let result1 = dbo
      .collection('user')
      .findOne({ id: `${id}` }, (err, result) => {
        if (err) console.log('err :', err);
        console.log('result :', result);
        // ctx.body = JSON.stringify(result);
        //ctx.redirect('/main');
        return result;
      });
    console.log('result1 :', result1);                        <====here
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server running on port ' + port);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For callBack

```
require('dotenv').config();
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';
const serve = require('koa-static');

const bodyparser = require('koa-body');

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const Router = require('koa-router');

const router = new Router();

app.use(bodyparser());
app.use(serve('../client/review-app/dist/review-app'));
app.use(router.routes());
MongoClient.connect(url, async (err, db) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  const dbo = db.db('review');

  // router.get('/', (ctx, next) => {});

  router.post('/loginAsk', (ctx, next) => {
    // ctx.redirect(`www.naver.com`);
    const { id } = ctx.request.body;
    const { pw } = ctx.request.body;

    let result1 = dbo
      .collection('user')
      .findOne({ id: `${id}` }, (err, result) => {
        if (err) console.log('err :', err);
        ctx.redirect('/main',{result:JSON.stringify(result)});
        return result;
      });
    console.log('result1 :', result1);                        
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server running on port ' + port);
});
```